# find multi-line string in text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find the multi line string in the text file using below script but it's not working as expected.

```
$tns= "MYSID=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydnshostname)(PORT = 1111))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYSID)
    )
  )"

$SEL = Select-String -Path T:\Test\search.txt -Pattern $tns


if ($SEL -ne $null)
{
    Write-Host "Contains String"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not Contains String"
}
```

Comment: The code is  not working*

Comment: when you use `Select-String`, the `-Pattern` is a _regex_ pattern. your pattern contains multiple special regex chars [`()` for instance]. try using `-SimpleMatch` to get a non-regex pattern match.

Comment: or do `Select-String ... -Pattern $([regex]::Escape($tns))`

Comment: please post a realistic sample of the input file you are working with, AND the exact info you want from it. i doubt that you really want that whole multiline string. i suspect you can use a simpler pattern to get the actual info you want.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the file's line endings.  In windows, lines ending in `\r\n`, one way is this.  With a match, it will return the whole file.

```
echo one '(two)' three four five | set-content file.txt
get-content -raw file.txt | select-string '\(two\)\r\nthree\r\nfour'

one
(two)
three
four
five
```

Or using regex single line mode `(?s)` where a `.` can match a line ending.  It should work with unix line endings too `\n` .  Without the pipe, select-string can't seem to match multiple lines (`-path` parameter).

```
get-content -raw file.txt | select-string '(?s)\(two\).*three.*four'
```